# Select a DataGridView row after TextBox value C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 1 column with some rows. I want to do :
When an user write a value in TextBox, if that value already exists in datagridview, I want to select the row which contains that TextInput value

How to do that ?
I'm going to use like this :

```
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, index];
```

But I don't know how to find the index using TextBox value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop through the rows until you find one that matches the value of the textbox:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    // Test if the first column of the current row equals
    // the value in the text box
    if ((string)row.Cells[0].Value == textBox1.Text)
    {
        // we have a match
        row.Selected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        row.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!dataGridView1.Rows[i].IsNewRow)
            {
                if (dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                else
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```